# How to add CDN to bundle.config in asp.net webforms bundling

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I am using asp.net bundling / minification and putting everything in bundle.config like this:

```
<styleBundle path="~/css/css">
  <include path="~/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <include path="~/css/flexslider.css" />
  <include path="~/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <include path="~/css/Site.css" />
  <include path="~/css/orange.css" />
</styleBundle>
```

But I would like to use bootstrap.css from a CDN:

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
```

So how can we do this in the bundle.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you cannot mix and match and pull some of the files in your bundle from an external source like a cdn.  You could upload the entire bundle to a CDN and configure the helpers to render a reference to the bundle in a CDN, but you cannot include files from external sources, the files must live somewhere that your app can find.

You could work around this by implementing a VirtualPathProvider that was able to fetch files from your CDN at runtime, but you would have to build that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET documentation may be able to help you out - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification, there is a section called **Using a CDN**.

Comment: That doesn't speak to using a bundle.config

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix bundles, but you can include an outside source in your boundle config.

Here es an example picked from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) as randomidea pointed out.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
            jqueryCdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

// Code removed for clarity.
}
```

We need to enable CDN, to do so we set UseCdn to true and we add the url in the ScriptBundle constructor. The include file is going to be used in debug mode.

As the article suggest, we need to have a fallback mechanism in case our CDN fail:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")';
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);

        }
    </script>
```

Hope this helps.